# Zend framework Database config to get Resultset

Tags: php, mysqli, zend-framework2, adapter

I have setup zf2 DB adapter for mysqli, using the below configuration:

```
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Mysqli',
    'database' => 'db_name',
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
        => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
    ),
),
```

and using below code to create the connection:

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$this->adapter = $sm->get('db');
```

The connection works and I can query database, my problem is that I am getting 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Result' instead of a resultset object which I want.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
code used for querying DB:

```
$this->adapter->query("SELECT * FROM `users`")->execute();
```

The code above returns a Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Result object

Comment: Have you read the docs here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html#quickstart ?

Comment: yes I still don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, so I can't tell what you're doing wrong.  Show your code attempting to follow the example I linked you to, and then I can help.

Comment: I am not sure what I should be doing in order to get the result set object thats my problem

Comment: What have you tried?  Your configuration looks fine, but you say "I can query the database" -- show the code that does that!

Comment: So my link does answer your question.  Look at the example code there.  It addresses your issue precisely.

Comment: realized what is done in the link. thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to documentation provided by timdev helped solve the problem, if this code is present you turn the MysqliResult object into a Result set

```
if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
    $resultSet = new ResultSet;
    $resultSet->initialize($result);
}
```